# flutter jsonDecode() causes error while decoding a string from firestore

Tags: json, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So, here I tried to fetch some data from the firestore and when I tried to decode it, it causes some error.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
E/flutter (32531): {version: 0, origin: {username: -, sessionId: 6660915144009228326, sessionV...
E/flutter (32531):  ^
```

The code for it is

```
firebaseInstance.doc(docId).collection("sdp").doc("offersdp").get().then((value) async {
String offersdp = value.data()["sdp"];
var session = jsonDecode(offersdp); //At this line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do  not need to decode FireStore response as its already in map format

```
String offersdp = value.data()["sdp"];
```

this above variable will container value stored in field "sdp"